# How to get images listed in sonata admin bundle backend

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sonata-admin

I want to get my image thumbnail listed in list area, i don't know how to do that, can any one please help me. I Got my caption in back end. I am using Sonata adim bundle and following its official document.

here is my imageAdmin.php

```
namespace swaam\ImageUploaderBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class ImageAdmin extends Admin
{

// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('caption', 'ckeditor', array('label' => 'Ca   ption'))
//            ->add('file', 'entity', array('class' => 'swaam\ImageUploaderBundle\Entity\image'))
            ->add('file', 'file', array('data_class' => 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File'
            ,'property_path' => 'file'
            ))

            ->end(); //if no type is specified, SonataAdminBundle tries to guess it
        ;
    }

// Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('caption')
            ->add('thumbpath')
        ;
    }

// Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('caption')
//            ->add('thumbpath')
              ->add('thumbpath')
        ;
    }
}
```

Here is my configureListFields method after updating

```
 protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
//            ->addIdentifier('caption')
//            ->add('thumbpath')
//              ->add('thumbpath')
            ->add('thumbpath', null, array('template' => 'swwamImageUploaderBundle:Admin:list_image.html.twig'))
//            ->add('thumbpath', null, array('template' => 'swwamImageUploaderBundle:Admin:list_image.html.twig'))

        ;
    }
```

and here is my twig

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field%}

    <div>
        {#<img src="{{ image.webPath | imagine_filter('gallery_element_admin') }}" />#}

        //<img src="{{ app.request.scheme ~ '://' ~ app.request.host ~ '/' ~  image.getthumbWebPath }}" />
        {# or whatever to create src of image #}

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to create custom admin field template. 
In *configureListFields* method add:

```
->add('path', null, array('template' => 'AcmeBundle:Admin:list_image.html.twig'))
```

And create file *AcmeBundle/Resources/views/Admin/list_image.html.twig* with content:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field%}
    <div>
        <img src="{{ object.webPath | imagine_filter('gallery_element_admin') }}" />
        {# or whatever to create src of image #}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: i have updated the code, with your code, and i didn;t get any error, still i didn't get any picture there.

Comment: View page source, find image tag and check image src address (try to open) or <img> tag is missing? You should also notice {# #} is a commnet in twig.

Comment: extremely sorry , but as i am new to symfony even php, still not sure how to get make path in twig, can u please show me any stuff example. i am  searching but unable to get any solution.

Comment: Take a look on: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html -
getWebPath();
This should give you full web related path. My imagine_filter is from https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle (not required)

Comment: This didn't work for me.
Template is not being load.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore with Symfony 4. The location of the templates has been changed and their referencing too. Does someone know hot to adjust this snippet to work with Symfony 4?

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar and this is my result after a while of searching the internet.

I have added tbe template in the configureListFields method from the admin class:

```
        ->add('culture', "string", array(
            'template' => 'AEWBackendBundle:CRUD:list_culture_image.html.twig'
        ))
```

I have created the template in the view:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field%}
    <div>
        {% set flag = web_path ~ 'images/flags/' ~ object.culture.name(object) ~ '.png' %}
        {% if file_exists(flag) %}
            <img id="culture_image" title="{{ object.culture }}" src="/images/flags/{{ object.culture.name }}.png" height="15" />
        {% else %}
            <img id ="culture_image" title="en" src="/images/flags/default.png" height="15" />
        {% endif  %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In parameters.yml:

```
web_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/
```

In config.yml:

```
twig:
    globals:
        web_path: %web_path%
```

Created the TwigExtension.php file to use the file_exists PHP function as a twig extension

```
<?php

namespace AEW\FrontendBundle\Services\Extension;

use \Twig_Filter_Function;
use \Twig_Filter_Method;

class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    /**
     * Return the functions registered as twig extensions
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'file_exists' => new \Twig_Function_Function('file_exists'),
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'twig_extension';
    }
}
```

Added the config lines in config.yml for the new extension:

```
parameters:
    aew.twig_extension.class: AEW\FrontendBundle\Services\Extension\TwigExtension

services:
    aew.twig_extension:
        class: %aew.twig_extension.class%
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Hope this helps you or anyone else who is looking for this info in the future.