# How to display a photo in Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I want to manage my users using SonataAdminBundle. On the show action (view details of one user), I have his profile photo and I just want to display it.

I think that I should change something in `detail.html.twig` but I don't know what...

Thank you

EDIT : close, see my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, we must create a new template especially for the photo.

===> [How to get images listed in sonata admin bundle backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365113/how-to-get-images-listed-in-sonata-admin-bundle-backend)